# How do I make a button in C# that executes a file without being installed on the machine?

Tags: c#

So I recently wanted to try out C# and make an app that executes a file on a button click without the file being installed on the machine so the button downloads it silently and executes it once downloaded.

So I tried the following code hoping that it will execute the .exe but it only downloaded it without running it. Here's the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace InvizCheatz_Loader
{
    public partial class InvizCheatz : Form
    {
        public InvizCheatz()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/CF-Multi_Tool.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code downloaded the file although I wanted to do it silently + open it automaticaly.

Comment: Step 1: download. Step 2: launch. You're trying to do them both in a single operation. Separate the two steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to download the file before you can start it!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string LinkToFile = @"https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/CF-Multi_Tool.exe";
        string FileName = "CF-Multi_Tool.exe";

        string filePath = DownloadFile(LinkToFile, FileName);
        StartFile(filePath);
    }


    string DownloadFile(string link, string fileName)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //download the file and renamed it
        wc.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
        //return the path where the file is
        return Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
    }

    void StartFile(string filePath)
    {
        //start the process
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Also how do I do it if I want that for multiple buttons, all I get is errors

Comment: in what way, what should the buttons do?

Comment: should the button download other files? i need information :D

Comment: Yeah but i managed to find it my own.All I had to do is change the "DownloadFile" to "Downloadfile1" (and so on) if you know if i can do that in any other way im all ears :)

Comment: Oh no... I have a bad feeling. Would you like to show your code

Comment: Hello! Please refer to this pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/raw/Zu9efiEt as you can see for each button instead of "DownloadFile" string I used "DownloadMemTest" and "StartMemTest" and some other changes.

Comment: I thought so haha :D No, you can use the "function" several times. Wait, I'll just create the right one and make a new answer out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Functions or methods (whatever you want to call them) you write once and then you can use them again and again.

I have now taken 4 buttons as an example, and you can expand it as you wish. That is what functions are for

See like This:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string LinkToFile = @"https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/CF-Multi_Tool.exe";
            string FileName = "CF-Multi_Tool.exe";

            string filePath = DownloadFile(LinkToFile, FileName);
            StartFile(filePath);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string LinkToFile = @"https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/memtest.exe";
            string FileName = "memtest.exe";

            string filePath = DownloadFile(LinkToFile, FileName);
            StartFile(filePath);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string LinkToFile = @"https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/CF-Multi_Tool.exe";
            string FileName = "CF-Multi_Tool.exe";

            string filePath = DownloadFile(LinkToFile, FileName);
            StartFile(filePath);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string LinkToFile = @"https://invizcheatz.com/Downloads/CF-Multi_Tool.exe";
            string FileName = "CF-Multi_Tool.exe";

            string filePath = DownloadFile(LinkToFile, FileName);
            StartFile(filePath);
        }


        string DownloadFile(string link, string fileName)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            //download the file and renamed it
            wc.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
            //return the path where the file is
            return Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
        }

        void StartFile(string filePath)
        {
            //start the process
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah it worked so i need to put the `string DownloadFile(string link, string fileName)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            //download the file and renamed it
            wc.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
            //return the path where the file is
            return Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + fileName;
        }

        void StartFile(string filePath)
        {
            //start the process
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
        }
    }` at the end of the code for them to function. it works

Comment: Right, you could also write it all in the button function, but that's not clean programming. Always program so that you have to write it once and you can use it again and again, like here.

The principle is simplified like this:

"string DownloadFile(string link, string fileName)"

it returns a string (return)
its name you can call it with is "DownloadFile" (but don't forget the round brackets so "DownloadFile()")

and you have to pass it 2 things, so in this case 2 strings

Comment: your a life savior ty!